# where is the documentation for Array()?

Tags: ruby, arrays, syntax, documentation

Browsing the [ruleby](https://github.com/Codalytics/ruleby) source code, I noticed that they were calling [Container(:and)](https://github.com/Codalytics/ruleby/blob/master/lib/dsl/ferrari.rb#L31), which is something I rarely see. In fact, the only other place I've seen it is in the [fabrication gem](http://fabricationgem.com)

A quick look showed that [Container subclasses Array](https://github.com/Codalytics/ruleby/blob/master/lib/dsl/ferrari.rb#L87), and a quick hop into `Pry` showed that `Array(:anything) #=> [:anything]`.

Another quick look at the ruby documentation for [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) doesn't shed much light on to this question.

What method is being called by `Array()`, where is it documented, how can one define a method like this, and is it considered "bad form" in ruby?

Comment: Your question doesn't match the title.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, the answer is that it makes an array of its parameters.

For your second, I have no clue, but it's simple enough.

For your third, here it is: In Ruby, defining a global method with the same name as the class is considered good form only when used to construct or convert from object of that type of a more fundamental type. You should not define this method unless you are creating some sort of low type. You could define this for some class like `BigInt128` but you shouldn't for `ObscureOrSpecializedType678`. There is also a design for these methods.

If the data that you are passed is of the returned type, return it. If the data is of a directly related type, perform obvious conversions (`Fixnum` to `BigInt128`). If the data passed in can be converted and is somewhat related (`String` to `Fixnum`) convert it (this conversion is usually only for `String`). If the data can not be converted, throw an exception. You should **NEVER** return a "magic value".

The other use of this method is to create a semi-literal syntax for non-literal types. The best examples of this are `Rational()` and `Complex()`. These functions, in addition to doing conversions, allow you to create rations and complex numbers in a more natural way (`Rational(1, 2)` vs. `Rational.new(1, 2)`). If there is a certain argument list that is simpler to the literal representation of a type, you would define a `Classname()` method.

For the most part, these methods are only part of the core language, and unless you are making a class like `BigInt128` or `FancyString` or `NaturalNumber`, you should not define these methods.

---

From what I know the defined of these are:

- `Array(*args)` -- Returns arguments as an array
- `Complex(real, complex)` -- Create a complex number with given real and complex parts
- `Float(arg)` -- Returns `arg` converted to a float (takes things like strings too)
- `Integer(arg)` -- Same as `Float()`, but converts to an integer(floats are truncated)
- `Rational(numerator, denominator=1)` -- Creates a Rational number with the given parts
- `String(arg)` -- Converts argument to string by calling `to_s`

Also, some classes define `[]` as a class method, which is used for more complex initialization from basic data types (usual initialization only, not conversion) such as `Hash[]`.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I think this answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is really it, but made some tests with iurb and I guess it is only a helper funcion to create a new Array.

Given I have this class

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(arg)
    puts "Initialized with #{arg.to_s}"
  end
end
```

then I can define a helper function like

```
def MyClass(arg)
  MyClass.new(arg)
end
```

and here you go

```
irb(main):009:0> MyClass(1)
Initialized with 1
=> #<MyClass:0x4770e10>
```

Answer (score 1):

uhhhh, since you're in Pry why not ask Pry to show you the documentation?!?!

```
[25] (pry) main: 0> show-doc Array

From: object.c in Ruby Core (C Method):
Number of lines: 4
Owner: Kernel
Visibility: private
Signature: Array(arg1)

Returns arg as an Array. First tries to call
arg.to_ary, then arg.to_a.

   Array(1..5)   #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[26] (pry) main: 0> show-method Array

From: object.c in Ruby Core (C Method):
Number of lines: 5
Owner: Kernel
Visibility: private

static VALUE
rb_f_array(VALUE obj, VALUE arg)
{
    return rb_Array(arg);
}
[27] (pry) main: 0>
```

Comment: because I don't know how to use the tools I have apparently. Thanks, that's an awesome feature I had no idea about.